# How to add a sql database to an elastic pool programmatically?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-elastic-scale

I have the following console application which creates a ShardManagerDB and creates one database for each company on the main database.
I can see on azure the databases created on the server however they are not on the elastic pool.

Question:
1. Is this doable with the current API?
2. If not, what are other recommended approaches?

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using mynm.Data;
using System.Linq;
using mynm.Models.GlobalAdmin;

namespace mynm.DbManagementTool
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SetupSSM();
        }

        //This will create the Shard Management DB if it doesnt exist
        private static void SetupSSM()
        {
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder connStrBldr = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                UserID = SettingsHelper.AzureUsernamedb,
                Password = SettingsHelper.AzurePasswordDb,
                ApplicationName = SettingsHelper.AzureApplicationName,
                DataSource = SettingsHelper.AzureSqlServer
            };

           DbUtils.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists(connStrBldr.ConnectionString, SettingsHelper.Azureshardmapmgrdb);
           Sharding sharding = new Sharding(SettingsHelper.AzureSqlServer, SettingsHelper.Azureshardmapmgrdb, connStrBldr.ConnectionString);
           CreateShardPerCompany(sharding);
        }

        private static void CreateShardPerCompany(Sharding sharding)
        {
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder connStrBldr = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                UserID = SettingsHelper.AzureUsernamedb,
                Password = SettingsHelper.AzurePasswordDb,
                ApplicationName = SettingsHelper.AzureApplicationName,
                DataSource = SettingsHelper.AzureSqlServer
            };

            UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
            ConfigurationDBDataContext context = new ConfigurationDBDataContext();
            context.Empresas.Add(new Empresa()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Nombre = "company name 1",
                NIT = "873278423",
                NombreRepresentanteLegal = "myself",
                TelefonoRepresentanteLegal = "32894823",
                NombreContacto = "myself",
                TelefonoContacto = "32423"
            });
            context.SaveChanges();

            var listofEmpresas = unitOfWork.EmpresaRepository.Get().ToList();
            foreach(Empresa empresa in listofEmpresas)
            {
                DbUtils.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists(connStrBldr.ConnectionString, empresa.NIT);
                sharding.RegisterNewShard(SettingsHelper.AzureSqlServer, empresa.NIT, connStrBldr.ConnectionString, empresa.Id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the sharding.css

```
internal class Sharding


  {
        public ShardMapManager ShardMapManager { get; private set; }

        public ListShardMap<int> ShardMap { get; private set; }

        // Bootstrap Elastic Scale by creating a new shard map manager and a shard map on 
        // the shard map manager database if necessary.
        public Sharding(string smmserver, string smmdatabase, string smmconnstr)
        {
            // Connection string with administrative credentials for the root database
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder connStrBldr = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(smmconnstr);
            connStrBldr.DataSource = smmserver;
            connStrBldr.InitialCatalog = smmdatabase;

            // Deploy shard map manager.
            ShardMapManager smm;
            if (!ShardMapManagerFactory.TryGetSqlShardMapManager(connStrBldr.ConnectionString, ShardMapManagerLoadPolicy.Lazy, out smm))
            {
                this.ShardMapManager = ShardMapManagerFactory.CreateSqlShardMapManager(connStrBldr.ConnectionString);
            }
            else
            {
                this.ShardMapManager = smm;
            }

            ListShardMap<int> sm;
            if (!ShardMapManager.TryGetListShardMap<int>("ElasticScaleWithEF", out sm))
            {
                this.ShardMap = ShardMapManager.CreateListShardMap<int>("ElasticScaleWithEF");
            }
            else
            {
                this.ShardMap = sm;
            }
        }

        // Enter a new shard - i.e. an empty database - to the shard map, allocate a first tenant to it 
        // and kick off EF intialization of the database to deploy schema
        // public void RegisterNewShard(string server, string database, string user, string pwd, string appname, int key)
        public void RegisterNewShard(string server, string database, string connstr, int key)
        {
            Shard shard;
            ShardLocation shardLocation = new ShardLocation(server, database);

            if (!this.ShardMap.TryGetShard(shardLocation, out shard))
            {
                shard = this.ShardMap.CreateShard(shardLocation);
            }

            SqlConnectionStringBuilder connStrBldr = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connstr);
            connStrBldr.DataSource = server;
            connStrBldr.InitialCatalog = database;

            // Go into a DbContext to trigger migrations and schema deployment for the new shard.
            // This requires an un-opened connection.

            using (var db = new ElasticScaleContext<int>(connStrBldr.ConnectionString))
            {
                // Run a query to engage EF migrations
                (from b in db.Terceros
                 select b).Count();
            }

            // Register the mapping of the tenant to the shard in the shard map.
            // After this step, DDR on the shard map can be used
            PointMapping<int> mapping;
            if (!this.ShardMap.TryGetMappingForKey(key, out mapping))
            {
                this.ShardMap.CreatePointMapping(key, shard);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the code implementing database creation: DbUtils.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists() -- you are probably using a T-SQL CREATE DATABASE command to Create an Azure database on a logical server.  Currently CREATE DATABASE doesn't support specifying the Pool -- however an update to Azure DB is expected within the next month that will extend the functionality of CREATE DATABASE and ALTER DATABASE to specify the Pool name as well.

In the meantime, you can make a REST API call from the CreateDatabaseIfNotExists() routine to add the database to the pool once it is created, using the Update SQL Database command:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163677.aspx.

However, making a rest call from inside your c# can be complex, and is discussed here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client .  It may be simpler to wait for the upcoming support in the CREATE DATABASE command, which would require a very small modification within your CreateDatabaseIfNotExists() routine.

Comment: @stuart can you provide where you got that information about assigning a db to a pool via tsql? Would like to read the source.  Thanks!

Comment: Sure -- see the Disqus comment from Morgan Oslake from "10 days ago" at the conclusion of this article: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-pool-portal/